# Android Programming: Calling function with different input using onClick

Tags: java, android

I am new to android programming and so please pardon if the question looks stupid.

I am creating a Calculator in Android and for the user interface I have many buttons (around 20 for 10 digits, and various operation). Now there is a string expression that I calculate once the user presses the button "=". However if he presses any other button then the input is updated. Say he presses "1" then input =1; then he presses 2 then input becomes "12" and so on. 
So I need to call the same function whenever various buttons are pressed, but the input to the function is different.
I can go-by this by making n different functions, one for each button but that is not very scalable.
So how can I go about it?

The current xml file is:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/Button01"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/Button03"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Button03"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Button03"
    android:onClick="UpdateExpression_/"
    android:text="/" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Button02"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/Button01"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Button01"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Button01"
    android:onClick="UpdateExpression_X"
    android:text="x" />
```

I need to update to android:onClick="UpdateExpression" and mention some input to this function call.

Thank you.

Comment: You can assign the same onClick listener to each button, and handle accordingly based on which button called the listener.

Comment: @jamis0n: How do I known which button called the listener?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a central onClick method, let's call it `updateExpression(View v)` Also a note about your code: method names should start with a lowercase letter, it's a Java naming convention.

```
  android:onClick="updateExpression"
```

Now the implementation:

```
public void updateExpression (View v)
{
  switch (v.getId())
  {
    case R.id.button1:
    //do stuff here
    break;
    case R.id.button2:
    //do other stuff here
    break;
  }
}
```

The reason you need `v.getId()` is because you're checking the id of the button then doing something if it's that particular id. This logic is needed since all your buttons will implement that same method.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
One more question. I need a global variable string exp that stores the expression and is updated whenever a button is pressed. I have mentioned it in the Stings.xml under resources as '    <string name="exp"> </string>' However when I use it in this updateExpression function as "case R.id.Button01:    exp=exp+"/"   break;"  I get the error that exp is not found. What is the problem?

Comment: You need to access it with `String exp = getString(R.string.exp);` However, this seems like an uncessary step to me, a global String in your Activity should suffice, just make sure when you update the text to use that new String. This is something trivial, so it's up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the implementation using code....

In the onClick function, compare the `v.getId()` to each of your Android layout ids, like `R.id.button1` `R.id.button2` etc...

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Here are some buttons defined in the XML layout as button1, button2, etc...
    Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);        
    button1.setOnClickListener(myListener);
    Button button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);        
    button2.setOnClickListener(myListener);
    Button button3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);        
    button3.setOnClickListener(myListener);

}

//Create an anonymous implementation of OnClickListener
private OnClickListener myListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
      Log.d(logtag,"onClick() called");              
      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "The " + v.getId() + " button was clicked.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
};
```